# Use Apple monitor as second monitor for windows pc

Tags: display, windows, thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I've an Apple monitor 27' with thunderbolt port, such the one in the picture below. Do you know how if it could be used as external monitor for a windows pc, that has not thunderbolt port?

[image]

Comment: Probably easier to get a mac laptop to go with it...

Comment: @SolarMike
I've a macbook pro, and it works just fine with it... But I also need to connect the monitor to a windows pc. Do you know if is it possible (no matter how it's difficult)?

Comment: Well, I connected an SGI 17" monitor to a mac laptop years ago and need to build the adaptor and work out all the RGB and interlacing to get the synch signals - good luck, or perhaps finding a monitor that has inputs to match both laptops may be easier. But search on other stacks : this might be interesting : https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9338

Comment: This as well : http://pinoutguide.com/SerialPorts/apple_thunderbolt_pinout.shtml

Comment: Or this : https://superuser.com/questions/834723/how-to-properly-solder-apples-thunderbolt-to-vga

Comment: I would think that if you can find a Thunderbolt video card compatible with your PC you could plug the monitor directly into that video card. Unless, of course, it's a laptop or a PC with no available expansion slots.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add thunderbolt to the PC for this to work. Sorry there’s not a better fix.

- [HDMI to Thunderbolt Display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408706/hdmi-to-thunderbolt-display)